# array get params on zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, get, parameters

I am working with zend framework and I want to know how to pass array params to zend url. I mean:

```
lala.com?foo=123 => lala.com/foo/123/
```

What about

```
lala.com?foo[]=123&foo[]=456 => ???
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible at all. See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2986